# Калькулятор на Js select * radio

Tags: javascript, radio

Есть калькулятор подсчета примерной стоимости дома.
При выборе либо заполнения каждого поля они умножаются друг на друга.
Все работает, но ни как не могу выдернуть значение по радио кнопки..

*Код использую следующий:*

Заранее скажу что только начал изучать js..
был бы признателен за помощь

```js
$('#obs, #visotp, #etagey, input[name="stena"]').bind('input', calcAndShow);

function calcAndShow() {
  var v1 = parseFloat($("#obs").val());
  var v2 = parseFloat($("#visotp").val());
  var v3 = parseFloat($("#etagey").val());
  var v4 = parseFloat($('input[name="stena"]').val());


  $('span#mainresult').html(v1 * v2 * v3 * v4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="obs">Общая площадь дома</label>
<input type="text" name="obs" id="obs" value="" data="Цена От">
<span class="sup">м<sup>2</sup></span>

<div class="selects">
  <select name="visota" id="visotp">
    <option disabled="" selected="">Высота потолков</option>
    <option value="1.5">Высота</option>
    <option value="2.5">Высота 2</option>
    <option value="2">Высота 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="selects">
  <select name="etagey" id="etagey">
    <option disabled="" selected="">Кол-во этажей</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1.5">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>
</div>



<span class="title"><span>Стены</span></span>

<input type="radio" name="stena" data-price="1.5" value="Кирпич">
<input type="radio" name="stena" data-price="2.5" value="Деревянный каркас">
<input type="radio" name="stena" data-price="3.5" value="Газоблок">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[name="stena"]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Когда даете ответы, хорошо бы оставлять минимальные пояснения, как ваш код работает.